# Airflow creates too many connections and crashes MySQL RDS server

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, airflow

I am using Airflow connections to pull and process data from an RDS SQL instance. The problem is that the process is generating over 21 connections (though my concurrency is set to 4 in the cfg file) and the RAM is overloading. I wouldn't expect to have any more than 6 - 8 connections at a time based on how I've set the process up. Is there a good cfg file setting or admin panel option that will allow me to control this behavior? I have tried updated `sql_alchemy_pool_recycle` but that hasn't fixed the problem.

[image]

You can see where the system performance starts tanking on the gant chart as the number of connections increase and the RAM on the RDS instance saturates:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In airflow you can limit heavy concurrency stuffs via POOLs, you can set pool size and operator won't go beyond the pool size. https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#pools

Comment: This seems like it might work, but I now have another problem: `WARNING - DagRun for capone_preproc 2017-10-12 18:32:40.342831 does not exist`. Can I get rid of this warning somehow by editing the metadatabase directly? What's happening is I'm debugging firing externally triggered runs and then deleting them. This seems to be inserting noise into the meta DB.

Comment: You can set up the logging level I believe in 1.9 based on this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1045

Comment: @Chenghzi It's hard for me to tell if the pool is working -- I created a six-task pool that I send these jobs to but I still have more connections than I would expect (17) and the 2GBs of memory is still just about maxed out. That said, the process is running more smoothly than before.

Comment: And roger, I'll check out the logging level

Comment: You can edit the metadata to remove those warnings, but chances are you'll hit something similar. The webserver, scheduler, and workers are have a cache of active dags and tasks.

What connection library are you using under sqlalchemy?

Our setup isn't exactly the same as yours (we're running aurora-cloning-mysql), but we're running ~100 concurrent tasks and we don't see more than a peak of 6 concurrent connections.

Comment: One final note: airflow very much does not do well with large numbers of small tasks. It is much more efficient to make a custom python operator that runs concurrently.

There are exceptions, of course, but the overhead from having so many concurrent kernels (even with celery), the drag on the scheduler (which is really the weakest part of airflow, stuck as it is in one thread) juggling so many queued tasks, and the lag on the db with so many task updates all scale really poorly.